# How to reload templateUrl in AngularJS custom directive?

Tags: angularjs

In a custom directive I am updating the scope (to update the scope("orderItem") I click on button on HTML file(templateUrl) which call the function to update the scope ) and displaying in the templateUrl, so for this I need to reload the html page (templateUrl)
            how to reload it ? following is my sample code.

```
        ##main.js

            .directive('orderItemDetails', function () {
                return {
                 restrict: 'E',
                 scope: {
                  orderItem: '=', // this scope is injected from some other js file.   
                 },
                    templateUrl: 'orders/orderItemDetails/orderItemDetails.html', // in this html file i am displaying the "orderItem" (scope) data.

                    // RUPESH
                    controller: function ($scope) {
                        $scope.loadHistory = function () { // function loadHistory() is called when button on  orderItemDetails.html is clicked

                            // from REST call i get data here, using this data i update the "orderItem" scope.
                            function (data) {
                                $scope.orderItem.history = data.statusHistory;// here i am updating the "orderItem" (scope). 
                                $scope.$apply();

                            },
                            function (code, text, xhr) {

                            });
                        }
                    }
                };
            })


    // here the scope orderItem is injected before calling the loadHistory() method
        ##details.html  

        <order-item-details> // again this data comes from somewhere else
            order-item="selectedOrderComponents.fulfilmentOrderItem.data">
        </order-item-details>

    // following html file include the html file which displays the data
        ##orderItemDetails.html
                    <ng-include src="'orders/orderItemDetails/orderItemHistory.html'"></ng-include>

        ##orderItemHistory.html  // the file to display the data         
            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="loadHistory()">Load History<i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
            </button>

            <table>

                <tbody>
               // here from scope "orderItem" the data is displyed 
                <tr ng-repeat="statusChange in orderItem.orderItem.history.statusChanges">
                    <td>{{statusChange.changeDate  | date: dateMask}}</td>
                    <td>{{statusChange.status}}</td>
                    <td>{{statusChange.subStatus}}</td>
                    <td>{{statusChange.errorCode}}</td>
                    <td>{{statusChange.errorDescription}}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>


        I want the updated "orderItem" (scope) value to be displayed in the  orderItemDetails.html file.
        but its not working right now. whats wrong ?

        [I am using AngularJS 1]
```

Comment: format your code well in it's container, thanks.

Comment: i have edited the post  and added the html file

Comment: when i change your function to `loadHistory();` it works for me, check out.

Comment: sorry i updated that,  loadHistory(),  when i call this method then i get data using Rest ,  and i update orderItem scope with that data.  but unable to reflect in html page.

Comment: it's because you need to call it with data argments.

Comment: you need to call it with data argments. ? i didn't get you  iam new to Angular

Comment: your arguments should have been populated with data stuffed with statusHistory properties, where ever you take the code from, apply it properly to fit yours. i stuffed the function with random data and it worked well at my end.

Comment: This question is poorly written and hard to follow due to the formatting.  In the future, try to clean it up as much as you can so it's easy to read and clear what you are asking.  I'm stating this just to help get you the best answer to your question.

Comment: in my project this html page is included into another html page (i dint write that file here), the scope has already some data injected by another js file(directive was called there and arguments passed), no when i clicked the button i got data using rest and updated the scope then how we refresh the html file ?  does it get refreshed automatically  ?     please let me know if you need more info.  its not working my side.

Comment: I had a similar requirement at work.  If it's a rest based call from a service, then you need a promise as it's asynchronous.  So no the way you are doing it won't work.

Comment: @rupeshkumar you haven't provided sufficient infos, and the code you linked is not syntactic, we look for more infos from your side.

Comment: @JamesDrinkard i guess once the data received from "nowhere", the scope.$apply() would update the controller automatically.

Comment: Agreed.  That is why I used a similar code example as I wasn't clear what your code was doing.  By the way, Angularjs has lots of 1x versions, so that might help knowing which one it is?  May not make a difference, but it adds to clarity.  I also don't know what the scope.apply is doing.  I don't believe it's needed.

Comment: @Abra001   i have updated the post  but unable to post it ..every time i post it gives error

Comment: @Abra001   yeah now i posted the updated code

Comment: @JamesDrinkard  : sorry for unclear post, i had to extract it from my project, now i have made it more clearand  posted.  please let me know what to do in this scenario.

Comment: No need to apolgize, just wanted to point out that the better the question, the better the answer.  You have a working solution now and I see what the apply is doing, but a better way is to use a promise.

Comment: @JamesDrinkard  thank you its working fine my side now all problems got solved

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine.

If I work off your mysterious REST call with my proper changes into it, the template gets changed accordingly because `$scope.$apply();` has for role to update the controller after each json call.

[check here](https://plnkr.co/edit/zTi1K3FzyaDimmia2Xke?p=preview) I hope that helps.